# OpenSSL - IPv6 support

Tags: c, openssl

I have a C app, and I'm using OpenSSL ver 1.0.2d.
I want to know, if it has support at IPv6.
I saw some other questions here, but without any answer, and in the official OpenSSL website, the documentation says:

> Major changes between OpenSSL 1.0.2h and OpenSSL 1.1.0 :
>    - Reworked BIO networking library, with full support for IPv6.

So maybe the IPv6 support start only at the 1.1.0 version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSSL is indifferent to IPv4/IPv6.
What's matter is the BIO - if you are using your socket or the BIO socket (and then, IPv6 is not supported)

Answer (score 1):

I found that:

they say that IPV6 is 80% working on 1.0.2d.v6 tested with testssl.sh.(drwetter commented on 26 Sep 2015 )

From:

https://github.com/drwetter/testssl.sh/issues/11

Hope it helps,